# Align panels with backgrounds correctly?

Tags: java, awt, panel, frame

I recently started with Java GUIs a few weeks ago and I have a difficulty with alignment.
Basically, I'm trying to have two Panels with a different background image (top Bar and content) and I want to align them one after another.
The problem is, that I can't use `BorderLayout.NORTH` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, because the background image loses his original size and gets very tiny.

How can I align them correctly, without losing the original size?

Here's my code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageFrame frame = new ImageFrame("topBar.png", "contentImage.png");
    frame.setSize(640,480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image img;

public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());    
}

public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

}

class ImageFrame extends JFrame {
public ImageFrame(String topBar, String body) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ImagePanel topPanel = new ImagePanel(topBar);
    ImagePanel bodyPanel = new ImagePanel(body);
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(bodyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
}
}
```

Comment: Show us some example code or screen shots

Comment: Allright, I added my code :)

Comment: You can create the panel by [WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/quick_start) and see what it generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues that popup out at me

1. You're not calling `super.paintComponent`. This is very important and can not be understated
2. You really should be using `ImageIO` to load your images. Ala from the fact it supports a wider range of image formats, it also loads images concurrent and throws useful exceptions when something goes wrong
3. You're not supplying any `preferredSize` values. This is used by the layout manager to decide how best to layout your component. Remember though, this are only hints and layout managers are well within there rights to ignore them

Check out [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details on `ImageIO`

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I'll look it up! I added the preferredSize values and the UI is now shown correctly. I just can't add new Components on the Panel (f.e. Labels) but I think that the super.paintComponent and ImageIO will fix it! :D

Answer (score 2):

> ..the background image loses his original size and gets very tiny.

That is because the preferred size for a panel is 0x0 until components are put in it.

There are at least two ways to solve this:

1. Add content to the panels.
2. Override `getPreferredSize()` to return the `Dimension` of the image.

The first is optimal, but I'll show how to do the 2nd (less code).

[image: Image Test]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageFrame frame = new ImageFrame();
    //frame.setSize(640,480);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image img;

public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
}

public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // a panel IS an ImageObserver, so use it here.
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    int w = img.getWidth(this);
    int h = img.getHeight(this);
    return new Dimension(w,h);
}

}

class ImageFrame extends JFrame {
public ImageFrame() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,2));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    ImagePanel topPanel = new ImagePanel(new BufferedImage(200,20,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
    ImagePanel bodyPanel = new ImagePanel(new BufferedImage(200,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB));
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(bodyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
}
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a great code! I even can add new components to the panels. I can't think of a better solution, thank you! Stay Fresh!

Comment: *"I can't think of a better solution,"*  I can think of several.  The first was listed in my answer, while the 2nd idea described would 'mess with the first'.